# Como compilar todos os arquivos .less em um único .css

Tags: gulpjs

Estou tentando configurar o Gulp no meu projeto porém quando compilo os arquivos .less ele gera um novo .css para cada .less, eu queria que o Gulp compilasse todos os .less e o resultado fosse apenas um "result.css". segue o meu gulpfile.js atual abaixo:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    reload = browserSync.reload;

// Compiles less on to /css
gulp.task('less', function () {
  gulp.src('src/**/*.less')
    .pipe(plumber())
   .pipe(less())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('src'))
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});

// reload server
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
});

// Reload all Browsers
gulp.task('bs-reload', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});


// watch for changes on files
gulp.task('watch', function(){ 
  gulp.watch('src/**/*.less', ['less']);
  gulp.watch("*.html", ['bs-reload']);
}); 

// deploys
gulp.task('default',  ['less', 'watch', 'browser-sync']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui solucionar meu problema, bem simples, na task less eu substitui o .src por

```
gulp.src('src/main.less')
```

E nesse main.less chamei os outros arquivos com o @import

```
@import "home.less";
@import "variables.less";
```

O resultado foi os dois arquivos compilados em um único arquivo, o main.css